# Java os.version property returned by Windows 2012 R2 and Windows 2016

Tags: java, properties, operating-system

What is the return value from

```
java.lang.System.getProperty(property)
```

for properties specific to OS? I mean:

- os.name
- os.arch
- os.version

I need to write a program (jjs script) which checks against Windows 2012 R2 and Windows 2016, but I don't have an access to boxes with that OSs.

Is there any place I can check these values? Kind of a list for all operating systems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that a Google search indicates a variety of attempts to create a list (almost all of which are out of date in some fashion) seems to indicate a lack of a definitive list. Further, I'm concerned that Oracle itself seems to have issues from time to time in getting an intelligent response created (see [this bug where Windows 8 was returning "Windows NT (unknown)"](https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8000344)).

To avoid many of these issues, and I understand it is pulling in an alternative library, we have found the `apache.commons.lang3.SystemUtils` to be useful, though I note it does not appear to have a definition for `Windows 2016` ([see bug entry for Windows Server 2016])[2](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8162776).

**For the specific versions, assuming the details in the bug reports are correct, one should expect:**

- Windows 2012 : "Windows Server 2012 R2" [Patch Description](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IV66449)
- Windows 2016 : "Windows Server 2016" [A patch commit](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u-dev/jdk/rev/8430a707e22b)

Though please note here are clearly Java version constraints.

Comment: I need it for a jjs script which validates environment. As I found it is possible to add dependencies to the jjs script (https://github.com/stevestorey/jjs-with-deps), but it involves maven. As I have no control over the environment the script will be running I would rather avoid that. However I think that 2nd part of your answer gives me what I need.